# setting up a class to store constant values which can be used throughout application

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to declare variables in class file of a control and to use them in ascx file on load itself but with no success (doing first time asp.net app)

for example:

in .cs

```
    public void OnInit()
    {
        int username = "John";
    }
```

then in ascx:

```
<a href="<%=username %>">test </a>
```

But this throws me error that username was not defined. I have tried Page_Load, Init too with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

username is only visible within the INIT/LOAD event, in order to vieew it like you have, you'll have to make a public property and then assign it from within the Load/Init event.

```
public string username;

public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   username = "john smith";
}
```

---

**EDIT - Based on updated comments**

page.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NameControl1.strUsername = "John";
}
```

page.aspx

```
<%@ Register Src="~/Name.ascx" TagName="Name" TagPrefix="TEST" %>
<TEST:Name ID="NameControl1" runat="server" />
```

name.ascx.cs

```
public int strUsername;
private int Username
{
    get{return strUsername;}
    set{strUsername = value;}
}
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = Username;
}
```

Comment: also you'll want to assign your username variable to a string, and not an int

Comment: That worked, I was missing the declaration before the function...thanks a lot

Comment: Yeah Colin, actually the function was little bit manipulated to share here, so misssed it out by mistake thats ok... :)

Comment: It is working everywhere except when adding control files...like <%@ Register TagPrefix="_include" TagName="userBlock" Src="~/users/" + username + "/name.ascx" %> it works fine if i replae username with John but when i use username it throws errors Parser Error Message: The server block is not well formed.

Comment: Thats because you cant embed a variable within a register tag. in this case you will need to assign the property in the Page_Load event of the page that registers the control, example: name.strUsername = "john" where you have public string strUsername{get;set;} in your control. Look for "parameter passing to controls"

Answer (score 0):

object sender, EventArgs eUse public property.

```
   public string username{set;get;}
    public void Page_Load()
    {
        username = "John";
    }    
In  ascx :

  < a href = "<%=username %>">test < /a>
```

Comment: Hi Pmtamal, that worked fine but not on OnInit,,,,,I had to  use Page_load Instead but thanks a lot for giving me the idea to declare a var